# Hit by a bus - can I use a dent puller to fix this?

Tags: repair, body-work, dent, accident

It turns out that two vehicles shouldn't occupy the same space at the same time :(

[image: Side View of Damage]

Thankfully the damage is superficial.

As the local dealership is notorious for its long body shop waiting list, I was wondering if it is worth addressing the dents in the rear quarter panel.

**Could the dents (especially the ones in the wheel arch) be straightened out with a hot-glue-based, plastic-tabbed [dent puller](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24369/675)?**

I'm not asking about the paintwork as I'm pretty sure the car will need respraying since there are a few deep scratches in the paintwork. The taillight will need replacing as well.

Comment: This question is very subjective, Zaid. It really depends on your skill level with such a device, doesn't it? Also depends on the type of dent puller you're talking about ... I can think of three or four off the top of my head.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have never pulled dents with a dent-puller that requires you to hot-glue plastic tabs onto the paintwork (was thinking of ordering one). That's what I had in mind. But this question shouldn't be treated as a "Can I do it?" (highly subjective) but rather a "Can it be done?"

Comment: Can you post photos from the underside of the wheel arch? If there are not to many plastic panels you could perhaps apply force from the inside?

Comment: I think you'll have trouble with the ones in the arch - I'm sure you can pull them out, but the metal has creased, particularly at the top of the biggest dent, so I think it'll always show...

Comment: Everybody is being kinda nice here... The answer is no, it can't be done at home and make it look good. What you may be able to do is find a wrecked car of the same model / color, and pull the panel off and use that. That's a decent DIY option...

Comment: @cory why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Zaid, I posted it for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2016-10-Oct 24 at 20:13, as [cory](/users/19403/cory) said in a comment

> [...] no, it can't be done at home and make it look good. What you may be able to do is find a wrecked car of the same model / color, and pull the panel off and use that. That's a decent DIY option...

Answer (score 2):

The dent is right over the wheel well, just loosen or remove the wheel well plastics (maybe 2 or 3 screws), then use some padded vices or similar to bend/pop/coax out the dents. I think you'll have more flexibility working with it in this manner. There's only so much pulling can do without getting at the back side of the panel. After buffing out the scratches I don't think it will look half bad.